# Consecutive SSH connections with Eclipse RSE

Tags: php, eclipse

I want to develop remotely in PHP on a development server. Eclipse RSE is great for this. But the only way to access my development server is by establishing a SSH connection to a firewall and then to the virtual server. Is there anyway to set up Eclipse RSE to do this?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered writing a script to copy files from a local directory to your remote server as they change?

Comment: That's a very good suggestion. I'll do it if I can't figure out how to get everything working in Eclipse. Right now I am coding in JED, which is fine. =)

Answer (score -1):

i do the same using netbeans remote option over SFTP
u can also coos ftp
works fine for me.

Comment: OP mention that he need to establish SSH tunnel first due to firewall.